# Do we want to allow meta commentary in questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, private-beta, rules, meta-commentary, broken-windows

Many Stack Overflow users remove meta-commentary in questions and answers. Whatever reasons they might have, do we want that meta-commentary to be allowed in GenAI SE during the "limited private beta"?

Meta commentary in answers might be helpful to include criticism of the question and the answer itself as a reflective exercise about why the question and answer should be used or not as a reference for future questions and answer.

In Meta Stack Exchange and other places, the "broken window" metaphor was used to explain that harmful posts attract bad posts. A meta-commentary might help explain why the post is terrible and should not be used as a reference. This also will help to avoid repeating the history of infamous questions posted in the early days of Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites, like, IIRC, Joel Spolsky's question about using Logo. Joel Spolsky is one of the Stack Overflow founders. He is one of the speakers discussing Stack Overflow at a developers' conference next week.

It will be nice to have Joel's input about this.

Reference

- [Joel Spolsky's infamous question, revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1003841/1)
- [Stack Overflow at WeAreDevelopers World Congress in Berlin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391338/)

Answer (score 2):

/help/privileges/comment says:

> When should I comment?
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;

I think a degree of meta commentary fits within that definition if it's constructive criticism.

> When shouldn't I comment?
>
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

It's fine as long as it doesn't go into extended discussion (use chat for that). There's meta and chat for that.

Getting consensus on things that need it should happen on meta where it's more visible.

If you want to express something that can be expressed as a close vote, just close vote.