# Contributions to questions that IMHO need more work

Tags: discussion

I was told through comments, some in an inappropriate way and others in a very civil and assertive way, that my comments to questions were inappropriate. While I respectfully disagree, I will try a different approach instead of focusing on my writing style and the words chosen. Instead of leaving a brief comment criticizing the post here, I will post contributions too large to be posted as comments and might not be directly applied as an edit as they might change the OP's original intentions.

Related

- [Meta is terrible to having debates. It might be possible add ArgDown (complex argumentation syntax)?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/12)
- [Do we want to allow meta commentary in questions and answers?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/12)
- [What are the best practices to have debates in GenAI Meta?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/12)
- [We are still looking to define the tone and quality standards of GenAI SE among other critical attributes](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/99/12)

Comment: I have doubts if this might be a good idea, however, I think that this is better than pointing OP's to an external site / platform. As some of my answers already got upvotes and comments from the OPs of the corresponding questions, I'm perceiving this exercise as helpful and appropriate for [genai.se]. Any suggestions about improving this post or a better way to handle what I'm doing here?

Answer (score 1):

## [How to have LLM's continue their response](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/152/12)

Coder Gautam YT: Welcome to GenAI SE.

The SO Inc. public Q&A platform works differently than other online communities on the Web. One of the characteristics is that questions and answers on the GenAI SE should not include "thanks". For details, please check out [Expected Behavior](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Note: this answer is posted in GenAI Meta; the norms here are slightly different. For details, please check out [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Another characteristic that makes the SO Inc. public Q&A platform different that other online communities is that questions should be specific; in other words, each post of type question should contain only one question. It looks that your question has multiple questions.

Please edit your question:

1. Remove "thanks"
2. Focus your question on a single question. You might make clear that your post contains a single question by avoiding including multiple question statements. This might be ridiculous to people used to other online communities. Remember that this is an international community, and not all the community members what the same communication skills. Choose the most straightforward way to write your questions whenever possible without sacrificing clarity and the required details to get a proper answer.

Comment: Agreed, the presence of multiple questions is an issue in this question.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful feedback. I have rephrased my question a bit, please check.

Comment: The "Needs more focus" close reason exists on all sites. Why do you need to post a meta answer to do what other can in the comments?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Please read https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/110/12

Comment: @Wicket Are you expecting me to reread the text or the linked meta questions?

Comment: I perceived that you haven't read the question. If you have read it, please elaborate on your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

## [Can an LLM be constrained to answer questions only about a specific dataset?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/167/12)

Welcome to [genai.se]. On questions including links in the way that you did, it usually is requested to add the relevant part or a summary directly into the question body. Several rationales for this are commonly summarized as referring to community norms requiring that posts be self-contained.

1. Linked content might change, moved or deleted. In whatever case, the links might point to a different content that was initially and might no longer meet their purpose.
2. If the linked content is not necessary to communicate clearly what is being asked, they are "noise", "fluf", and "chit chat". They should not be included per standard public Q&A norms, more specifically per [Expected Behavior](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: The reason I add the links is: 1. These forums expect people to show they've done the necessary research before posting. 2. The links lead to similar questions which others may find useful if they reach my question with the intention of finding what the links lead to. 
I didn't understand what you meant by adding the summary to the question body. Do you mean I should include a summary of what is linked to, for each link?

Answer (score 0):

## [Is there a way to gauge how environmentally (un)friendly popular genAIs are?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/151/12)

As regular GenAI tool users, we must rely on reports sponsored by large research institutions or on articles about such reports. Due to current trends and economic and political interests, it will be convenient not to limit ourselves to a single source.

The most common starting point for regular computer users is to search on Google; others might prefer to start at an online place run by a non-profit organization like Wikipedia. People having high information literacy skills might go directly to specialized sources like research centers and research publications; some might use Google Scholar or other specialized research engines.

Employees and students might have access to "paywalled" research reports as part of the benefits of being part of the corresponding organization, i.e., Garner Group.

### Google results

Here are some results returned by Google (https://www.google.com). Specifying the domain is relevant, as results are customized considering the domain, among other factors.

- [Current Climate: Big Tech’s Massive Carbon Footprint](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alanohnsman/2023/03/04/current-climate-big-techs-massive-carbon-footprint/)

### Related Wikipedia articles

- [Carbon footprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_footprint)
- [Carbon accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_accounting)

### Google Scholar

TBD

Comment: Feel free to just edit my questions if you feel they can be meaningfully improved.  I try my best, but I'm human and can overlook things.  In the end, I just want an answer.  (You're getting the Google results I got [e.g. Samsung is a big polluter], which are not relevant to genAIs.)

Answer (score 0):

## [What is the exact number of web pages used to train ChatGPT-3.5, and what methods are employed to filter out inaccurate information?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/162/12)

Welcome to GenAI SE.

Not all questions work well in the Stack Overflow Inc. public Q&A platform. What is the actual problem that you are facing? Have you read the [tour](https://genai.stackexchange.com/tour)?

From the *tour*:

> #### Get answers to practical, detailed questions
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. | Ask about... - Specific issues with GenAI - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered |

Also, it's worth mentioning that questions should be specific. In this case, despite having a one-liner question, it contains two questions. Please edit the question queue to make it a good fit for this site.

Notes:

Two standard close reasons might apply:

1. Needs details or clarification commonly used for questions about the site topic but unclear, i.e., how this is relevant to others, what is the problem the OP is facing, etc.
2. Needs more focus for questions being too broad and asking multiple questions in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

## [Do LLMs suffer from a kind of Dunning-Kruger effect, giving an inflated self-assessment in domains it lacks expertise in?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/226/12)

People often attribute human qualities to non-human entities, as evidenced by queries like this. I'm proposing the tag user-psychology as it might be relevant to have answers from subject matter experts from this field. I think that some terms are [Anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism) and [Personification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification).

---

In the context of GenAI Stack Exchange, using "user-psychology" as a tag name instead of "psychology" may seem redundant. Still, it is necessary to avoid any misunderstandings about its intended purpose. "Psychology" should not be used because machines or software, and specifically LLM, have a psyche but because might think that they attribute having it and might try to interact with GenAI tools in certain ways that, in the best cases might be innocuous but could be dangerous both the user mental health as well to the use of the responses got from these tools.

---

Regarding using "this" ad link text despite being a practice extended among several SO/SE users I don't think that it's something that should be promoted. Instead, use meaningful text and more important add a brief summary or be explicit about what is the content about as posts on GenAI Stack Exchange should be self-contained, as I already mentioned it on [GenAI Meta](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

## [Generative AI Use Case for Search Domain](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/252/12)

This question looks to be a poll or survey. These kinds of questions usually aren't a good fit for the public Q&A platform as they can't get a definitive answer. However, a question stating a criterion to identify when an answer answers the question might be allowed.

AFAIK GenAI Stack Exchange is intended to be focused on using GenAI tools. It might need to be edited to make this migrated question a good fit for this site. The Ask Question guidance suggests showing "any research"; this includes showing what you have tried.

Related

- [Is it okay to ask for examples of genAI usage and output?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/12)